# Error when using a conditional forall in OPL

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I get an error in a OPL model when I use that constraint:

```
forall (j1,j2 in p: row[j1]==row[j2] && j1<j2)
```

where row is a variable:

```
dvar int row [p];
```

The error is like this:

```
Decision variable row not allowed.
```

I don't know why this is not possible, but how can fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks, for the works

Comment: Hi @G.S. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is slicing should be bound and should not contain any decision variable. You should rely on logical constraints:

```
range p=1..4;

dvar int row[p] in p;

subject to
{
 forall(j1,j2 in p) ((row[j1]==row[j2] ) => (row[j1]>=2));
}
```

This works fine.

Comment: Ok, but this is a linear constraint or not?

Comment: This is a logical constraint. And this will work fine.

Comment: Yeah I know all work, but I don't know if it is a linear constraint theoretical speaking. Because I need to have all  like linear constraint.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a logical constraint is not really a linear constraint. But as it can easily be transformed into a linear constraint (and CPLEX will do it automatically -- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_constraints_types_logical.html), the distinction is usually not done.